# SQL запрос на выбор топ категории

Tags: sql, сортировка

Имеются 3 таблицы (SALES, PRICES, KEY_CATS) Требуется вывести топ 5 самых продаваемых категорий за поседений год, их выручку, количество продаж. Я написал ниже запрос, который выводит только требуемые поля за последний год. Как мне изменить запрос так, чтобы он еще и отсортировал по количеству продаж и вывел топ 5?

```
SELECT SUM(PRICES.price * SALES.qnt) AS 'Выручка', 
       KEY_CATS.category, 
      (SUM(SALES.qnt)) AS 'Количество' 
FROM PRICES INNER JOIN SALES ON PRICES.item = SALES.item 
INNER JOIN KEY_CATS ON KEY_CATS.item = SALES.item 
GROUP BY KEY_CATS.category 
ORDER BY SALES.date DESC LIMIT 365;
```

Comment: вы написали запрос, который выводит не за последний год, а последние 365 записей по дате (то есть это может быть 365 продаж за последние сутки). Чтобы вывести за год, надо использовать каике-либо функции работы с датой, а-ля date_sub/add, diff и делать это в where. сортировку проводить обычными средствами ибо столбец количества уже доступен в сортировке поскольку она выполняется после группировки.

Comment: изменения цены в течение года  в вашей предметной области в течение года не бывает?

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь сортировку по количеству продаж, вместо даты, пишешь SELECT TOP(5) в самом начале, и добавляешь условие разницы текущей даты и даты реализации не более 365. Так у тебя выведутся топ 5 продаж по количеству за последний год :)